# How to swap rows inside a 3d tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix

I have been at it for two hours now and it is such a simple problem. I am building an optimizer for weights using GA and to perform mutation I need to be able to swap a row of weights in one NN with another NN

I have a 3d tensor for each layer of shape[population, total_input, total_output]. I pick out a row in the 3d tensor and then two individuals have to swap the values of the exact same row. For example row [nn1,row_to_swap] needs to swap with row [nn2,row_to_swap].

A example with an tensor of population 3, input nodes 3 and output nodes 2 has this shape [3,3,2] where I want to swap [0,0] and [1,0] :

```
      [[[ -0.08140966 -0.04416275 ],
        [ 0.08669635, -0.1681123 ],
        [ 0.06804892,  0.05393898]],

       [[ 0.11369397, -0.0822193 ],
        [-0.08230941,  0.16685687],
        [-0.08133464, -0.02710806]],

       [[ 0.08381592, -0.07583494],
        [-0.08355351,  0.07891247],
        [ 0.0392112 , -0.07686558]]]
```

It should look like this.

```
  [[[ -0.08140966 -0.04416275 ],
    [ 0.08669635, -0.1681123 ],
    [ 0.06804892,  0.05393898]],

   [[ 0.11369397, -0.0822193 ],
    [-0.08230941,  0.16685687],
    [-0.08133464, -0.02710806]],

   [[ 0.08381592, -0.07583494],
    [-0.08355351,  0.07891247],
    [ 0.0392112 , -0.07686558]]]
```

Just a heads up, I won't know what the exact shapes are for the tensors as they will be created with shape variable. Sometimes the methods might have to do multiple swaps. Say [1,0] and [1,2] will have to swap with [0,0] and [0,2] so if there is a method that can do multiple swaps in one go without creating a loop that would be great.

For example:

```
      [[[ -0.08140966 -0.04416275 ],
        [ 0.08669635, -0.1681123 ],
        [ 0.06804892,  0.05393898]],

       [[ 0.11369397, -0.0822193 ],
        [-0.08230941,  0.16685687],
        [-0.08133464, -0.02710806]],

       [[ 0.08381592, -0.07583494],
        [-0.08355351,  0.07891247],
        [ 0.0392112 , -0.07686558]]]
```

It should look like this.

```
      [[[ 0.11369397, -0.0822193 ],
        [-0.08230941,  0.16685687]
        [-0.08133464, -0.02710806]],

       [[ -0.08140966 -0.04416275 ],
        [-0.08230941,  0.16685687],
        [ 0.06804892,  0.05393898]],

       [[ 0.08381592, -0.07583494],
        [-0.08355351,  0.07891247],
        [ 0.0392112 , -0.07686558]]]
```

Numpy seemed to have a simple solution in which they used

```
npArray[[0,0]] = npArray[[1,0]]
```

Of course, TensorFlow is a bit more complicated.

Comment: In your first example, two tenosrs look the same. Also, is the input tensor shape (var1,var,var) or (var,var,var1)? In your example, it should be the later one, but you mentioned it's (var1,var,var) at the beginning.

Comment: Hi there, I fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using tf.scatter_nd_update. Please find a sample snippet:

```
ref = tf.Variable([[[1, 2,3],[3, 4,5],[5, 6,7], [7, 8,9]]])
print(ref)
indices = tf.constant([[0,1,1], [0,1,0], [0,0,0] ,[0,0,1]])
updates = tf.constant([9, 10, 11, 12])
update = tf.scatter_nd_update(ref, indices, updates)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(ref))
    print(sess.run(update))
```